# jQuery UI sortable event problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

in my code here http://jsfiddle.net/ebSf4/ you can drag from one sortable column to the other.  I am adding some animation to sortable's receive event to make the dropped element animate to the size needed in it's new position.  This is working great except the receive event fires late the first time you move a given element.  The element snaps to it's new size without animating.  This only happens the first time you move an element.  If you try moving the same one again it will animate as intended.  What gives?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that initially elements (.section) don't have a fixed width.
All you need to do is set the width before animating an element.
I've updated your fiddle code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jNzVY/